# How to put a multivalued attribute in one column in a query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

For example, in my database I have 3 tables,

- the Books table for storing data about books
- the Tags table for storing data about tags
- and a link table (the Book_Tags table) for storing information about a book having multiple tags.

Its illustrated in the image below... ("M" above the arrow means the many side of the relationship)

```
    BOOKS                    BOOK_TAGS                      TAGS
    +----+---------+         +---------+----------+         +----+---------------+
    |ID  |  Title  |         |Book_Id  |  Tags_Id |         |ID  |  Tag_Name     |
    +----+---------+         +---------+----------+         +----+---------------+ 
    |1   |  Book_1 | 1    M  |1        | 1        | M     1 |1   |  Tag_Name_1   |
    |1   |  Book_1 |<--------|1        | 2        |-------->|2   |  Tag_Name_2   |
    +----+---------+         |1        | 3        |         |3   |  Tag_Name_3   |
                             |2        | 1        |         +----+---------------+ 
                             |2        | 3        |         
                             +---------+----------+
```

My question is, how do i query my database so that i would get a result something like

```
    +---------------------------------------------------------+
    |ID  |  Book_Title  |   Tags                              |
    +---------------------------------------------------------+
    |1   |  Book_1      |   Tag_Name_1, Tag_Name_2, Tag_Name_3|
    |2   |  Book_2      |   Tag_Name_1, Tag_Name_3            |
    +---------------------------------------------------------+
```

And not something like

```
    +----------------------------------+
    |ID  |  Book_Title  |   Tags       |
    +----------------------------------+
    |1   |  Book_1      |   Tag_Name_1 |
    |2   |  Book_1      |   Tag_Name_2 |
    |3   |  Book_1      |   Tag_Name_3 |
    |4   |  Book_2      |   Tag_Name_1 |
    |5   |  Book_2      |   Tag_Name_3 |
    +----------------------------------+
```

Comment: This is a SQL Anti-Pattern.  Doing this breaks fundamental best pratices about relational database design.  The result you don't want is actually the best practice norm.

Comment: @Dems From a reporting perspective, that result could be fine - as long as you don't store it in the DB, it's not really an anti-pattern. The user interface display may show the book name, then the multiple tags separated by commas. I'd probably just do it as part of the UI code, but there are cases when string aggregation makes sense for result sets.

Comment: @NWest - That is, I suppose, a matter of opinion, perspective, etc.  But I would suggest that formatting data in the database is also an anti-pattern - It restricts re-use of code, etc; keeping the result set as a 'pure' normalised set enables re-use of code, simplifies debugging, etc, etc.  Formatting belongs in the presentation layer, data belongs in the data layer.  But then, depending on the use the application of strong separation of layers may be overzealous ;)

Comment: @Dems does that mean i shouldn't use this method for displaying the content of my database? is there any other way i could do to gain the  same result?...

Comment: @curzedpirate - I would recommend return the results you said you do not like.  Then, in your client/application/front-end, you take that data and reformat it.  You may just want a comma-separated list like you've shown here, you may want a tree-view, or some xml.  By keeping the "get the data from the database" step in the normalised form, you can more easily adapat and change your client/application/front-end to display it any way you want.

Comment: @Dems - I'm sorry but I don't quite understand... Do you mean I should make a code in the front-end side of the system and take each data in a multi-valued attribute one by one and append each of them to make up a combined data in a column?..

Comment: @curzedpirate Basically, yes, that sums up the suggestion. In general, having the front-end do this type of work is the typical way of handling it. There's many pros and cons on having this be done in the database or in the application layers, and you'll find many varying opinions on it. If you are writing a report, for example, that summarizes thousands of rows, it may make more sense for the database to handle it. It's all about the use case :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use GROUP BY Clause to aggregate results and do string append. So something like:

```
SELECT bk.Book_Title, GROUP_CONCAT(bt.Book_Id SEPARATOR ', ') FROM BOOK_TAGS bt
JOIN BOOKS bk ON bk.ID = bt.Book_Id
JOIN TAGS t ON t.ID = bt.Tags_Id
GROUP BY bt.Book_Id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT b.book_title, tmp.tag_name from books b
    INNER JOIN (
SELECT bt.book_id as book_id , group_concat(t.tag_name) as tag_name FROM book_tags bt 
    INNER JOIN tags t ON t.tag_id =  bt.tags_id
) tmp
    ON tmp.book_id = b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is sql query with auto increment ID.

> SELECT @temp:=@temp+1 AS ID, Book_Title, Tags FROM (SELECT title as
>   Book_Title, GROUP_CONCAT(tag_name) AS Tags  FROM (SELECT BOOKS.title,
>   TAGS.tag_name FROM (`book_tags` JOIN BOOKS ON BOOKS.id =
>   BOOK_TAGS.book_id) JOIN TAGS ON TAGS.id=BOOK_TAGS.tag_id) tbl  GROUP
>   BY title) AS tbl CROSS JOIN (SELECT @temp:=0) AS dummy